facebook prophet interaction terms
I have a univariate time series data on an hourly basis of patient census. I ran an ARIMA model with interactions on daily and weekly seasonality (periods t=24 and t=168 respectively) and found the interactions terms overall to be significant.
However, I am unsure how to add interaction terms (ie Monday_9AM, Tuesday_9AM, Wednesday_9AM, etc) for these 168 additional regressors for the prophet facebook model. Any suggestions?
